# How to solve Prometheus configuration error: file service discovery config must contain at least one path name

Tags: prometheus

I've been struggling with this. I'm trying to configure a file_sd_configs section in my prometheus.yml file. Here's the relative section:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: ct_agents
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - agent_configs/agents.json
```

At startup, I get this error:

```
time="2019-02-07T16:15:21Z" level=error msg="Couldn't load configuration (-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml): file service discovery config must contain at least one path name" source="main.go:208"
```

I have tried a variety of things based on examples I found elsewhere. I tried putting the path in single quotes like one example. I tried full path. I originally had a wildcard and an empty directory, hoping Prometheus would find the possibly dynamic list of files.

I've checked spacing multiple times. There are no tabs in the file (the most common problem I have when editing .yml files).

The file itself exists although is currently just an empty array (in JSON).

I'm fairly sure it's something silly.

Comment: When you navigate your browser to http://your-prometheus-server:9090/config - it shows the full name of the agents.json including path. Is it what you expected and where the file is located?

Comment: Prometheus won't stay up. I'm now looking at the code. Unfortunately, I'm not a go programmer. There is exactly one reference to that message. It's during unmarshalling of the files_sd_config code, and the error happens: if len(c.Files) == 0.

Comment: I think it's just a stupid YAML problem. Spacing. Dashes. Colons. Quotes. Braces. Something like that.

Comment: To complicated it: the documentation suggests to say "files:" while all the examples I've found are "- files:". But if I don't include the dash, I get a YAML parse error.

Comment: Your yaml is 1oo% correct, i tried it and it works for me. What version of Prometheus are you running?

Comment: Oh, this isn't a good sign. $ prometheus --version
prometheus, version 0.16.2+ds (branch: debian/sid, revision: 0.16.2+ds-1ubuntu1)
  build user:       pkg-go-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
  build date:       20160408-04:15:29
  go version:       go1.6

Comment: Ah yes, you're running a version that's about 2.5y old, pretty sure the file_sd format has changed since.

Comment: I installed with this: apt-get install -y prometheus. I'll dig into something that gets me something far newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Oliver's questions, we determined I was running an old version of Prometheus (installed with apt-get install prometheus). Installing a modern version was a pain, but it resolved the problem, once I got it configured again.

So -- if anyone is having problems getting this to work with the same error, check the logs to see how old your Prometheus binaries are. As of February, 2019, if you install using apt-get on a Docker Ubuntu instance, you get a very, very old copy of Prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

the error is well described in the error message:

> file service discovery config must contain at least one path name

Thus, it means your json file should have at least one target

```
  [
    {
      "targets": 
      "example.com"
      ],
    }
  ]
```

Comment: [
        {
                "targets": [ "somegarbage.com" ]
        }
] -- same error message

Comment: Same error if I also add a "labels" portion: [
        {
                "targets": [ "somegarbage.com" ],
                "labels": { "job": "myprogramname" }
        }
]

Comment: This was *not* the problem. It was a versioning problem. See the conversation above with Oliver.